# How to create custom login page in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I am new to Magento, how can I develop a sample login page?

Comment: is this same as customer login?

Comment: yes, this is same as the customer login

Comment: Please help me how to save data in database and after login how to redirect page into another html page

Comment: First you need to have strong grip on Magento code, how it works , then you can do coding .

Answer (score 1):

you can refer below snippet for your requirement

```
<custommodule_index_index>
    <update handle="customer_account_login"/>
//remove unwanted block from here if you don't want
</custommodule_index_index>
```

Thanks